# Fail to pass js variable to php via ajax

Tags: php, ajax

There were similar questions here, but I haven't found any solution to the problem. So I'm asking for help. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
              $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
                           var my_id = $(this).attr('id');

                             clear_field();
                             $.ajax({

                                    url:"my_action.php",
                                    type:"POST",
                                    data:{action:'Edit', my_id:my_id},
                                    dataType:"json",
                                    success:function(data)
                                    {
                                     alert(my_id);
                                   $('#my_name').val(data.my_name);
                                    $('#my_id').val(data.my_id);
                                    $('#modal_title').text('Edit');
                                    $('#button_action').val('Edit');
                                    $('#action').val('Edit');
                                    $('#formModal').modal('show');

                                    }
                                    })
                             });
```

Code in my_action.php:

```
  if($_POST["action"] == 'Edit')

                {


                    $data = array(
                                  ':my_name' => $my_name,
                                  ':my_id' => $_POST["my_id"]
                                  );
                    $query = "
                    UPDATE tbl_my
                    SET my_name = :my_name
                    WHERE my_id = :my_id
                    ";
                    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                    if($statement->execute($data))
                    {

                        $output = array(

                                        'success' => 'Data Updated Successfully'
                                        );
                    }

                }
```

$_POST["my_id"] is always blank.

Console shows 'Data Updated Successfully', and when I change :my_id to some value, everything works properly (the mysql table is updated). 
alert(my_id) shows proper id. So I have no idea what else to check

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Try remove `dataType:"json"`.

Comment: I have data passed in json (echo json_encode($output); in my_action.php). Anyway, tried and nothing changed

Comment: Try `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));` in my_action.php

Comment: returns string(39) "my_name=EDITED&my_id=&action=Edit"

Comment: Probably the header "Content-Type" is missing or is not "application/x-www-urlencoded"

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the `var my_id = $(this).attr('id');`n is actually returning any value? you can use `Console.log(my_id);` and check in the browser developer console or use `alert(my_id);` to check.

Comment: alert(my_id) returns id. There is some conflict, I guess, when variable is sent to my_action.php